# Unable to validate the following destination configurations((Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am adding a topic configuration for s3 bucket and getting the below exception:

Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument

I have already given lambda permission to s3 but still getting the exception. Please find the below code.

```
"Resources": {
    "s3Mock":{
      "DependsOn": "LambdaInvokePermission",
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
      "NotificationConfiguration": {
          "LambdaConfigurations": [{
            "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
            "Filter": {
              "S3Key": {
                "Rules": [
                  {
                    "Value": ".zip",
                    "Name": "suffix"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "Function": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "LambdaMock",
                "Arn"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    },
    "LambdaMock": {
      "DependsOn": "IAMPolicy",
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Ref": "Lambda"
        },
        "Description": "A Lambda function which will persist the data into RDS",
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket" :{"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${s3StackParameter}-BucketName"}},
          "S3Key" :"abc/adi-cpm-analytics-mock-lambda.zip"
        },
        "Handler": "adi-cpm-analytics-mock-lambda.lambda_handler",
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "IAMRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Runtime": "python3.7",
        "Timeout": 300
      }
    },
    "LambdaInvokePermission": {
      "DependsOn": "LambdaMock",
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaMock",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceAccount": {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        },
        "SourceArn": {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${s3StackParameter}-BucketArn"}}
            }
          },
```

Please let me know what i am missing in the code which will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

- The `s3StackParameter` parameter is undefined.
- The Lambda's name and role reference nonexistent `Lambda` and `Role` resources.
- You have defined a circular dependency, S3 -> LambdaInvokePermission <-> Lambda.

See this post for a proper example of creating an S3 bucket that sends notifications to Lambda: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/